# How to display a certain amount of information. Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, for-loop, selenium-webdriver

How to display a certain amount of information.
I am using selenium

I have 15 items displayed (there are 15 on the page). And I need to limit the amount of output information

(My English is bad)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\\VSProjects\\iwantgamessel\\chromedriver.exe")
url = "..."
driver.get(url=url)

with open('...') as f:
    content = f.readlines()

try:
    time.sleep(10)
    divs = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "game-info")
    for div in divs:
        atag = div.text
        for x in content:
            print(x + "\n" + atag)
        
    
finally:
    f.close()
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To restrict the amount of information you can use [*list slicing*](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-slicing/) as follows:

- To collect all the elements:

  ```
  divs = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "game-info")[::]
  ```
- To collect the first five elements:

  ```
  divs = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "game-info")[:5]
  ```
- To collect the alternative elements:

  ```
  divs = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "game-info")[::2]
  ```
- To collect the last five elements:

  ```
  divs = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "game-info")[:-5:-1]
  ```

Comment: and how to display the first five lines (from a file) along with a div

Comment: Sounds like a new question all together. Feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement.

Answer (score 1):

In case you know there are 15 elements there while you want to get only 10 or 7 of them you can use indexing of the list you are iterating over. As following:

```py
limit = 10
with open('...') as f:
    content = f.readlines()

try:
    time.sleep(10)
    divs = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "game-info")
    for idx, div in enumerate(divs):
        if idx < limit:
            atag = div.text
            for x in content:
                print(x + "\n" + atag)
```

Comment: the loop endlessly displays data, from the file in turn, and from the site the same data

Comment: Looks like this is caused by some additional code you did not share here. The code in my solution itself will end looping when `idx` reaches the `limit`

Comment: put all code on pastebin?

Comment: Preferably if you can paste it into the question itself. if not - some other way we will be able to see it correctly

Comment: Possibly my fault... Please see the updated answer and let me know if now it is correct

Comment: Unfortunately not working

Comment: Still looping as mentioned previously?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: I did this: for x in content[0:5], but it gave out 5 results 5 times –

Comment: What value did you set for `limit`?

Comment: I put 1 but I tried with 10 too

Comment: I see. But it looks like the problem here is not really with my solution but with the inner `for x in content[0:5]`. My `for` loop `for idx, div in enumerate(divs):` as I understand does iterates limited amount of times, not for all the values in `divs`  list. This is what you initially asked for

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you, but when I posted the question, I had not yet used 
    `fox x in content[0:5]`

Comment: OK, I didn't think of anything better than parsing photo links (the problem was that they were too long)

Comment: I can't understand what is the problem here and how to resolve it since I can't debug it. Especially since I'm mostly coding in Java, not Python :)

Comment: It's ok, you've been very helpful. There are no problems when parsing a photo, but there are problems when getting from a file