# Selenium Couldn't fetch all div tag

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, web-scraping

I tried to fetch all special div tag with a class of "someClass" from a [website](https://divar.ir/s/tehran/buy-apartment/parand?price=200000000-450000000&non-negotiable=true&has-photo=true&q=%D8%AE%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%87%20%D9%BE%D8%B1%D9%86%D8%AF)

Website need to scroll down to load new div elements
so I used Keys.PAGE_DOWN, that worked and scrolled but the data wasn't complete again

So I used:

```
elem = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "body")


no_of_pagedowns = 23

while no_of_pagedowns:
    elem.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
    time.sleep(0.7)
    no_of_pagedowns-=1
```

It will Scroll till the entire html page load
but when I want to write data in a file, it just write 20 div tag instead of hundred ...

Complete Code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

url = 'https://divar.ir/s/tehran/buy-apartment/parand?price=200000000-450000000&non-negotiable=true&has-photo=true&q=%D8%AE%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%87%20%D9%BE%D8%B1%D9%86%D8%AF'
driver.get(url)


elem = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "body")


no_of_pagedowns = 23

while no_of_pagedowns:
    elem.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
    time.sleep(0.3)
    no_of_pagedowns-=1

datas = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'kt-post-card__body')

f = open('data.txt', 'w')
counter = 1
for data in range(len(datas)):
    f.write(f'{counter}--> {datas[data].text}')
    counter += 1
    f.write('\n')

f.close()
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Which particular `<div>`s do you want to collect?

Comment: question updated, I want `div` with `class=kt-post-card__body`   @undetectedSelenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select only 20 `<div>` tag instead of hundreds you can use [*list slicing*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71610547/7429447) and you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*

  ```
  elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.kt-post-card__body")[:20]
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='kt-post-card__body']")[:20]
  ```

---

Ideally you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*

  ```
  elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.kt-post-card__body")))[:20]
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='kt-post-card__body']")))[:20]
  ```

---

### Update

To select all the `<div>`s:

To select all the `<div>`s you can use [*list slicing*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71610547/7429447) and you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*

  ```
  elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.kt-post-card__body")
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='kt-post-card__body']")
  ```

Comment: Thanks but `Exactly I need All Div Element (hunderds)`, I just want to get all div elements not 20  the problem was that. Also I remove `list slicing` and check your code, it wont work :( @undetected Selenium

Comment: @Mosihere Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: One time 20 items, another time 24. but I guess there are more than 100 items exists

Answer (score 0):

I checked the site and as I figured out they get data as json by using api and cursor. Cursor here made with a time expression and the variable called last-post-date. When entered to the site this value is given as lastPostDate inside a json.
To obtain data fastly from the site this requests can be used:
https://divar.ir/s/tehran/buy-apartment/parand?price=200000000-450000000&non-negotiable=true&has-photo=true&q=%D8%AE%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%87%20%D9%BE%D8%B1%D9%86%D8%AF
lastPostDate value should be taken from this link and lastPostDate value in the JSON below should be updated with it.

```
{"json_schema":{"category":{"value":"apartment-sell"},"districts":{"vacancies":["427"]},"price":{"max":450000000,"min":200000000},"non-negotiable":true,"has-photo":true,"query":"خانه پرند"},"last-post-date":1647005920188580}
```

This updated JSON should be sent to API link below as POST.
https://api.divar.ir/v8/search/1/apartment-sell

And a new JSON should be returned. And inside this JSON there is a “last_post_date”. New queries could be made by using this variable. Also required data is stored in this JSON.

This is just an idea. It seems to be working when I test it with POSTMAN.

Comment: I'll check it. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

### The Problem was implicit pagination!

So I use a for loop and each time update page number :)

```
for page in range(1, 11):
    url = f'https://divar.ir/s/tehran/buy-apartment/parand?price=450000000-200000000&non-negotiable=true&has-photo=true&page={page}'
    driver.get(url)
```