# How to pull the href information from specific class using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm currently working on some web scraping using python and selenium, and I can't seem to pull the link information from a href in an anchor tag for a specific class. for reference, its from zillow (specifically, this url : https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_rent/San-Francisco,-CA_rb/ ).

[image]

I've tried a few different options in order to select the anchor tag listed but can't seem to return the information i need :

```
links = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "list-card-info")
print(links[0].get_attribute('href'))
 -- returns 
None
```

also tried

```
links = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "list-card-top")
print(links[0].get_attribute('href'))
 -- returns 
None

links = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "list-card-link list-card-link-top-margin")
print(links[0].get_attribute('href'))
 -- returns 
None
```

and lastly

```
links = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "list-card-info.a")
print(links[0].get_attribute('href'))
```

I know I can pull all the anchor tags, but certainly there is a step im missing here to get the nested anchor tag value? or am i pulling the wrong class? not sure where im going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the value of the *href* attribute you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and using [*list slicing*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71640649/7429447) you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.zillow.com/san-francisco-ca/rentals/?searchQueryState=%7B%22pagination%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22usersSearchTerm%22%3A%22San%20Francisco%2C%20CA%22%2C%22mapBounds%22%3A%7B%22west%22%3A-122.62421695117187%2C%22east%22%3A-122.24244204882812%2C%22south%22%3A37.70334422496088%2C%22north%22%3A37.84716973355808%7D%2C%22regionSelection%22%3A%5B%7B%22regionId%22%3A20330%2C%22regionType%22%3A6%7D%5D%2C%22isMapVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22filterState%22%3A%7B%22fsba%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22nc%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22fore%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22cmsn%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22fr%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22ah%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%7D%2C%22isListVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22mapZoom%22%3A11%7D')
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class='list-card-top'] > a[href]")))])
  ```
- Using *XPATH* in a single line:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.zillow.com/san-francisco-ca/rentals/?searchQueryState=%7B%22pagination%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22usersSearchTerm%22%3A%22San%20Francisco%2C%20CA%22%2C%22mapBounds%22%3A%7B%22west%22%3A-122.62421695117187%2C%22east%22%3A-122.24244204882812%2C%22south%22%3A37.70334422496088%2C%22north%22%3A37.84716973355808%7D%2C%22regionSelection%22%3A%5B%7B%22regionId%22%3A20330%2C%22regionType%22%3A6%7D%5D%2C%22isMapVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22filterState%22%3A%7B%22fsba%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22nc%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22fore%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22cmsn%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22fr%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22ah%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%7D%2C%22isListVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22mapZoom%22%3A11%7D')
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='list-card-top']/a[@href]")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/San-Francisco-CA-94134/15166498_zpid/', 'https://www.zillow.com/b/avery-450-san-francisco-ca-BTfktx/', 'https://www.zillow.com/b/solaire-san-francisco-ca-65g7KK/', 'https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/117-Saint-Charles-Ave-San-Francisco-CA-94132/15195262_zpid/', 'https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/433-40th-Ave-San-Francisco-CA-94121/15092586_zpid/', 'https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/123-Carl-St-San-Francisco-CA-94117/2078490576_zpid/', 'https://www.zillow.com/b/fifteen-fifty-san-francisco-ca-BdnYPc/', 'https://www.zillow.com/b/l-seven-san-francisco-ca-9NJtD7/', 'https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/4642-18th-St-San-Francisco-CA-94114/332858409_zpid/']
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You could use XPATH to find the link (a tag) and use `get_attribute('href')` to get the link from the tag.

Like this:

```
href = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="list-card-top"]/a').get_attribute('href')
print(href)
```

Another example:

```
href = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="list-card-info"]/a').get_attribute('href')
print(href)
```

If you want to use `By.CLASS_NAME`, you could do it like this:

```
link = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "list-card-top")
a = link.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'a').get_attribute('href')
print(href)
```

In your case:

```
links = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "list-card-info")
print(links[0].get_attribute('href'))
```

You're trying to find an attribute named 'href' in that div element with class list-card-info. We actually want to get the 'href' from the a tag inside that div.